# Mesh deforming when weight paint is at zero

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting

When I rotate the neck bone, some of the buttons on my character's dress rotate too . . . even though the weight paint is blue. I have gone over the buttons several times to make sure that there is no low value weight paint there. I have also tried going into edit mode, selecting the neck bone under vertex groups and clicking remove. It should not be moving but it still does! Please help ASAP!

[image]
[image]

Comment: it might be the head bone that moves the buttons, also sometimes substract in weight paint mode doesn't work 100%, I don't know why, you should select the button vertices in Edit mode, then go in the Vertex Groups list and click on the Remove From All Groups function (on the dropdown menu on the vertex groups list) to make sure that no bone as any influence, then assign each button to the group it is supposed to be a part of, either with the Assign button or in Weight Paint mode.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, I am so relieved. I was am on a dead line and you saved me so much time.